# How does the Review page work?

Tags: support

If someone "Accepts" a suggested edit, is it automatically applied?

If someone "Rejects" a suggested edit, is it automatically killed?

Do several people have to approve/reject a suggested edit before it gets applied?

Why do edits by some users not seem to need to go through the Review process?

I'm struggling to find out about this aspect of the site in the Help Center, can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: See chat, prompted by an edit to an answer on [constant speed slope](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/18728/7044)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% positive, but I believe:

1. If the original poster "Accepts" the suggested edit, it is automatically applied. Or a moderator.
2. Same with "Rejects".
3. If the approvers/rejecters are not the original poster, then it takes two votes in the same direction to decide.
4. If you get to 2,000 rep, you get a privilege to edit without requiring review: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit

What privileges/powers you get as you earn rep: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/privileges?tab=moderation

Comment: thanks @freiheit